# Replace word even if it has empty HTML tags between it, which breaks it up

Tags: c#, pdf2htmlex

So this is a rather odd question, I know that. I use a tool called [`pdf2htmlEX`](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX), which converts a PDF to HTML. So far the results has been pretty damn impressive. I have yet seen a single error in all the PDFs I have converted to HTML.

With this HTML, I need to replace some strings dynamically with C#. However, I can't simply say `line.Replace("#SOME_STRING", "Another string")`, although I wrote `#SOME_STRING` in the document before exporting to PDF. Why not, you might ask? Because the output of [`pdf2htmlEX`](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) can look something like this:

```
<div class="t m0 x5 h5 ya ff4 fs3 fc0 sc0 ls0 ws0">#SOME_ST<span class="_ _5"></span>RING </div>
```

See that empty span-tag with a `_` and `_5` class? Yep, that prevents me from replacing my word. The `_5` class simply has some width (like `width: 0.9889px`).

In this case, how would I replace `#SOME_ST<span class="_ _5"></span>RING` with something else?

Here are some cases:

```
(#SOME_STRING)          #SOME_ST<span class="_ _5"></span>RING
(#SOME_OTHER_STRING)    #SOME_<span class="_ _7"></span>OTHER_ST<span class="_ _5"></span>RING
```

I'm kind of lost here, because I can't remove all the `_5` elements, because the class is randomized everytime I change something in the document.

EDIT: So I basically need a way to filter out the HTML tags from my own Key-Value pair, so I can replace the words like `#SOME_STRING -> SOMETHING_ELSE`.

Comment: Try to use regex which matches firstletter.<spanstuff>.restofword AND firstTwoLetters.<spanstuff>.restofword ..

Comment: If the class follows the pattern you showed you can use a regular expression: `"<span class=\"_ _\\d+\"> *?</span>"`

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex to filter all empty spans:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<emptyspan><span[^>]*></span>)", RegexOptions.None);
var strTargetString = @"<div class=""t m0 x5 h5 ya ff4 fs3 fc0 sc0 ls0 ws0"">#SOME_ST<span class=""_ _5""></span>RING </div> <span></span>";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    var emptyString = myMatch.Groups["emptyspan"].Value;
    // replace or remove empty string ??
}
```

Comment: The problem is as I said: I simply cannot remove all empty span-tags. The ones I can "legally" remove are the ones between my keys (`#SOME_STRING` for example). The rest of the empty span-tags do have classes that are needed by the document.

Comment: Then what about removing all spans that are between a word beginning with # ... that would be: `#\w*(?<emptyspan><span[^>]*></span>)\w`

Comment: So simply something like `Regex.Replace(line, @"#\w*(?<emptyspan><span[^>]*></span>)\w", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline` or?

Comment: Problem: What if  the line has multiple `#KEY`s? Because this just gives me some output I can't really explain what looks like. Half of each word is basically gone.